# When a Commit is completed from local GIT Repo

Tags: git

I am currently looking into distributed source code models and am wondering when the user 'commits' from their local repo to the main 'trunk'. Does their copy of the local repo stay in tact on the users machine, is it deleted at the point of commit or is it deleted but recoverable?

Apologies if this is an obvious question. However it is one that I am keen to know the answer to!

Comment: There is, conceptually, no main trunk and the changes aren't "committed" to remote repos, but "pushed". This is an important concept, because even if in your workflow there's an "upstream" repo that you think of as canonical, as far as the tools are concerned all repos are equal.

Answer (score 1):

A commit is never deleted, unless the branch it belongs to is itself deleted.

From its creation, it remains a persistent object that belongs to the repository history, and is transferred on push/pulls between synchronized repositories.

Answer (score 1):

Git being a distributed version control, the local repo is always in tact.  What you are calling a 'commit' would be a 'push' in Git.  This synchronizes the local repo with the remote so that all the changes on the local are also on the remote.